# why is my geometry fracturing/breaking apart during displacement/

Tags: displacement

[image]

Hopefully you can see the issue here. Geometry has been copied and remeshed from the one on the left which is made of triangles as I thought that might be the issue. But as I displace either one, instead of the mesh being bumpy as per the noise, it just comes apart face by face.

Comment: I sort of figured a workaround by remeshing it again in voxel mode and turning on smooth shading. That's the only thing that seems to work. And you have to turn on smooth shading.